# href to return nothing?

Tags: .net, asp.net, href

I have a user control in the modules folder of my project. and I have a link like 
Test in this control. When ever I mouseover this "Test" on the page, I can see the whole url like this "www.example.com\projectName\Modules". But I want to make it such a way that it should display the url as "www.example.com\projectName". I want to get rid of that modules folder name.

Comment: "Test" link is like "<a href="#">Test</a>"

Comment: in order to be a valid link it should have an url set on href attribute. If you want to use jQuery, add event handlers to mouse hover and leave on this link and on the handlers, you can set a custom value to window.status...

Comment: You might also want to use slashes instead of backslashes in your URLs.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming here you want to change the hover text that appears in the status bar?

To do some you could use the following inline script to do so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/somegarbage"
    onmouseover="window.status='http://www.google.com'; return true"
    onmouseout="window.status=''">Google</a>
```

This would produce a link with the text `Google` and when you hover over it the status bar text would show as `http://www.google.com` instead of the actual url which is `http://www.google.com/somegarbage`.

You can just change the code above to inject whatever you want by replacing the text being assigned in the `onmouseover` event.

Comment: Actually I found the solution Iam using like this

<a href='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>' runat="server"></a>

This is giving me the url correctly as I needed.

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you can get by without using the Page.ResolveUrl().  Try <a href="~/" runat="server">

Answer (score 0):

By default the Href attribute will just append the current url. So if you're on a page like

```
http://abc.com/projects/index.htm
```

and in the html for this page you have

```
<a href="about/index.htm">link text</a>
```

Then the resulting url will be

```
http://abc.com/projects/about/index.htm
```

However, if you prefix the href with a `/` character, then it will make the link relative to the site root and it will give you what you're looking for.

```
<a href="/about/index.htm">link text</a>
```

will go to

```
http://abc.com/about/index.htm
```

***So in your case....***

Make your link like this..

```
<a href="/projectName">Test</a>
```

Comment: I am trying to do like this
<a href='<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>'>Test</a>

<a href='<%=Request.RawUrl%>'>Test</a>

<a href='<%=Request.PhysicalPath%>'>Test</a>


But none of theese giving the right path

Comment: As you solution make it to work on my dev site, but if I take it to live I have only one absolute url. no project name nothing in it. So I want to make it to work on for both domains

Thanks

Comment: my dev site url is www.abc.com\ApplicationName

live site url is www.xyz.com

So make that url to work for both of them

Comment: If you start the URL with a /, it will use whatever the current domain name is.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set your <a> to runat server, you can do:

```
<a href="~/" runat="server">Test</a>
```